# SQL Inner Join related_Mahavir

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns ID,NAME,VALUE as 1,2,3,4,5/A,B,C,A,B/9,9,9,9,9 so I want total SUM for particular name e.g. A-18, B-18, C-9...please answer the query in SQL form.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show your code for proving how far did you try and help others members to understand your problem better while you will be providing a context of your issue. I remomend you read these following links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, SUM(value) FROM whatevertable GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking to sum the columns & get an output based on your column Name.

Select Name + '-' + ltrim(rtrim(str( sum(Value) ))) from 
tablename group by Name